# Why does mysqldump not backup procedures?

Tags: mysql, backup, stored-procedures, mysqldump

I am running MySQL 8.0.23 and try to backup/restore procedures. Therefore I created a user "dump@localhost" with the following rights:

```
> Grants for dump@localhost
> GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO `dump`@`localhost` 
> GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER ON `mydb`.* TO `dump`@`localhost`
```

Creating a backup like this:

```
 mysqldump -u dump -p -n -d -t -R mydb > test.sql
```

The command executes but no procedures are within the sql file.

```
--
-- Dumping routines for database 'mydb'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2021-12-25 17:21:39
```

However, if I use my own user account instead of "dump" or also using root, it will dump the procedures.

According to the MySQL 8 docu the provided rights should be sufficient:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used, and (as of MySQL 8.0.21) PROCESS if the --no-tablespaces option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

A typical procedure of mine looks like this:

```
create
definer = root@localhost procedure SUM_prices_d()
INSERT IGNORE INTO SUM_prices_d
...
```

What rights am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very strong likelihood you need one more grant:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO `dump`@`localhost`;
```

REASON : Dumping Stored Procedures requires reading from `mysql.proc`

### UPDATE 2021-12-25 12:20

According to [MySQL Documentation, you need global SELECT privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines)

> --routines, -R
>
> Include stored routines (procedures and functions) for the dumped
> databases in the output. **This option requires the global SELECT privilege**.
>
> The output generated by using --routines contains CREATE PROCEDURE and
> CREATE FUNCTION statements to create the routines.

You may need to adjust grants as follow

```
GRANT PROCESS,SELECT ON *.* TO `dump`@`localhost`
```

or create a separate user for the sole purpose of dumping stored procedures

```
GRANT PROCESS,SELECT ON *.* TO `dump_storedprocs`@`localhost`
```

Comment: I believe since MySQL 8.0.12 this table does not exist anymore. I am also getting a: [42S02][1146] Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist. https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/

Comment: That worked! Thank you.